# Binding tooltip text inside a DataGrid HeaderTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagridview

In the first column on my data grid I need to show a header and an image. Also the image has to have a tooltip with some dynamic text. I have used a HeaderTemplate as shown in the code below to show both text and the image. But I'm struggling to bind the ToolTipMessage to the TextBlock. I have also used a ProxyElement but it still doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
    <FrameworkElement
        x:key"DataContextProxyElement"
        DataContext={Binding}
        Visibility=Collapsed/>
</Grid.Resources>
<Border
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}"
    Visibility="{Binding ShowBorder, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding GridData}"
        Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="*"
                Binding="{Binding Term}"
                ElementStyle="{StaticResource Wrap}"
                EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource EditWrap}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Other synonyms"/>
                            <Image Source="{StaticResource InfoIcon}">
                                <Image.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource PowerUserToolTip}">
                                        <TextBlock Text={Binding DataContext.ToolTipMessage, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxyElement}}/>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </Image.ToolTip>
                            </Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Where is the ToolTipMessage property defined?

Comment: ToolTipMessage is defined in my ViewModel. Sorry I forgot to mention it on the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource InfoIcon}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource PowerUserToolTip}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.ToolTipMessage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}"/>
        </ToolTip>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```